# Why is VSCode Python not outputting function returns to the terminal?

Tags: python, bash, function, return

I'm fairly new to python and just started trying out VSCode. However, I created a function that is supposed to return a value, however when I run the program, nothing is outputting to the terminal. The programing I'm doing is part of a codecademy course. Here's the code;

```
destinations = ["Paris, France", "Shanghai, China", "Los Angeles, USA", "São Paulo, Brazil", "Cairo, Egypt"]
test_traveler = ['Erin Wilkes', 'Shanghai, China', ['historical site', 'art']]

def get_destination_index(destination):
    destination_index = destinations.index(destination)
    return destination_index

get_destination_index("Los Angeles, USA")
```

When I click run, all I get is this:

```
PS D:\Project\Location> & C:/Location/of/python3.11.exe/on/my/computer d:/location/of/script.py
```

I expected for the index of *"Los Angeles, USA"* in the list *destinations* to be outputted to the terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't print it, it won't be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the mistake in the code - you haven't wrote `print()` before calling the function. Here is the corrected code:

```js
destinations = ["Paris, France", "Shanghai, China", "Los Angeles, USA",
                "São Paulo, Brazil", "Cairo, Egypt"]
test_traveler = ['Erin Wilkes', 'Shanghai, China', ['historical site', 'art']]

def get_destination_index(destination):
    destinations_index = destinations.index(destination)
    return destinations_index

print(get_destination_index("Los Angeles, USA"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how I missed that. Still getting the hang of the basics of the language.

Comment: No worries, it's normal for beginners. By the way, I would appreciate it if you could make it a correct answer.

Comment: Please, avoid negative vocabulary, edited your question to remove it and to add some formatting